# Number of combination for a password

Tags: combinatorics

If a password can be anything from 00A0000A to 99Z9999Z is it right to say that the number of possibilities is ?

```
10 * 10 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 26 = 676 000 000
```

Comment: Yes if the slots with `integers can only be integers but the slots with letters can only be the letters of the alphabet.